# GregorianCalendar class not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, namespaces

I'm trying to use System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar, but Visual Studio 2013 is telling me:

> The type or namespace name 'GregorianCalendar' could not be found.
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The docs say it's in mscorlib and as far as I can tell that is supposed to get added automatically.

These are my namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

and this is the code I'm getting the error with:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
```

This Microsoft example page is where I got the `new GregorianCalendar()` code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkh94why.aspx

Comment: have you tried cleaning your solution?

Comment: Do you have any other compilation error? Maybe the compilation failed before they could link that using statement. And if not, have you tried `System.Globalization.Calendar c = new System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar();` directly, without the using? Or a good Build -> Clean, Build -> Rebuild can always help.